# Movie about weird black ooze inside this girl making her kill people

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I watched this movie easily before 2012 so I don't remember much. I remember a scene with a girl in a fridge with, I think, weird black venom substance. Later on there's a scene where she is like uncontrollably bleeding in a public shower and someone walks in. I think she seduced someone in a pool. I know it’s not *Jennifer's Body*, but I have no clue what else it could be.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. Could you take a look at [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335) and see if it sparks any extra details you could [edit] in?

Comment: Why was she in the refrigerator?

Comment: Was she holding that "weird black venom substance" somehow? In a bottle?

Comment: Maybe something from the "Species" franchise?  (I don't recall anything specifically that matches your clues other than it's scifi)

Comment: Any chance it could have been an X-Files movie (or even an episode)? The black oil was a pretty major element for a lot of its run.

Comment: Does the monster seemingly originate from a pile of bin bags under a bed? If so, this is probably a late 80s movie that I saw part of at my cousins as a child. Nightmarish stuff. Woman/monster is in the pool and she convinces a guy to get in, then eats him?